# Do malicious files uploaded via forms pose any threat before saving to disk?

Tags: python, django, security, ubuntu

I currently have a form that allows users to upload photos with Python/Django. I want to bypass all the issues of dealing with malicious files though and just upload them straight into an S3 bucket. My question now is, is it safe for me to

1. Accept the POST
2. Instead of saving to disk, just upload the photo straight into an S3 bucket in the backend

Or would I still be putting my server at risk just by accepting the POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what kind of maliciousness you are worried about.

- If you are concerned about your server being infected with a virus or something, then probably Yes.
- If you are concerned about "images" that might later be served up to another user by your webapp ... and then potentially infect the user's machine, then definitely No.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! Would you happen to know how to protect my server then?

Comment: If you are worried, use a virus checker.   But seriously, you need to be clear about who or what you are trying to protect.

Comment: I'm trying to protect the server from having a malicious file execute.

Comment: Well on Linux, files don't spontaneously execute.  And making sure that the file mode doesn't have the "executable" bits is probably sufficient to prevent accidental execution.  But running a virus checker is good too, to pick up stuff that might damage other systems running (for example) Windows.

Comment: Of course, it also depends on your level of paranoia :-)

Comment: Wait, you're saying as long as I don't execute it myself, it should be fine. But you also said I could infect my server just by accepting POST requests without writing to disk. Don't these conflict? Or is it still possible to execute a file in Python code without saving to disk? Because I'm thinking I could probably just get away with uploading to S3 straight away

Comment: *"But you also said I could infect my server just by accepting POST requests without writing to disk."*  - I said you could infect the user's machine.  Meaning the machine belonging to someone who uses your service.  There is no contradiction.

Comment: Look ... seriously ... you need to think these things through for yourself.  Think about the various people / parties are involved are.  And what you **should** be protecting against.

Comment: Right, I completely forgot about user safety. Thanks for walking me through this issue Stephen, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A malicius file can be use by hacker after uploaded to the server due to that it is excute(sometimes it can be accessed through browser).Usually, if the file you received doesnot have execute right, there is no risk.
but if you are still  concern about the file itself, you get do this:
1.check the format of the file.(only receive the jpg,png,etc.)
2.check the file header
3.donot return the real path of the file.

Comment: Hi Tiao, thanks for your input. So if I understand this correctly, as long as it's never executed, I'll be fine and so, by extension, even if I fail the checks you mentioned, will be fine as long as I don't write to disk?

Comment: do not give the file execute permission and it will be ok.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot Tiao!